# How to receive events from IE using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I need to evaluate the document from each browser window and act accordingly. I'm using shellwindows to obtain the IwebBrowser2. Then I have access to all the document properties I need. ie...

ShellWindows := TshellWindows.Create(nil);

...

ShellWindowDisp := ShellWindows.Item(Count); //for loop

...

ShellWindowDisp.QueryInterface(iWebBrowser2, WebBrowser);

etc....

This method works fine as far as I can tell. However, if one of the documents change my code will never know it. So I need to monitor Explorer for events such as OnDocumentComplete. Dumping the code above into a timer and comparing properties obviously is not the way to go. I've found several components that capture events but would rather not rely on a third party component for this. Since my knowledge on this area is limited I need to understand what is going on. Any good articles out there that explain how to approach this, preferably with simple source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access the events of the WebBrowser instances, you must get a pointer to the [`IConnectionPointContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface using the QueryInterface method of the [`IWebBrowser2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, then call the FindConnectionPoint method passing the GUID of the [DWebBrowserEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and finally call Advise method of the [`IConnectionPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to start to receive the events.

Something like so

```
var
 LConnectionPointContainer : IConnectionPointContainer;
 LConnectionPoint : IConnectionPoint;
 dwCookie: Longint;
begin
  //LWebBrowser2 is a IWebBrowser2 object
  LWebBrowser2.QueryInterface(IConnectionPointContainer, LConnectionPointContainer);
  LConnectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(DWebBrowserEvents2, LConnectionPoint);
  LConnectionPoint.Advise(Self, dwCookie);
end;
```

All this code must be implemented inside of a class which descends from IDispatch in order to receive the events in the Invoke method. As in your case you need intercept the [DocumentComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event you must check when the value of the *DispID* parameter is 259.

If you want a sample of this explanation, try checking this code [`intercept Internet Explorer messages.`](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2058)

Comment: Thanks RRUZ! It's been quite a while since I dealt with client/server automation events. My basic understanding was that the client queried the server but not the other way around. Using the server events model in reverse is slick I had no idea. Thanks!